# How can we send for loop variable as the function argument in python

Tags: python, function, return

i wanna send the value of i to fun() function in and want to receive it as the 3rd argument in the range function .

```
for i in range(1,11,fun(i)):
       print(i)
```

error i am getting is :

```
Name Error: name 'i' is not defined
```

i have tried defining i as global but it didn't workout because both the 'i' have different id's .
for eg:

```
global i 
print(id(i))
for i in range(1,11,fun(i)):
     print(id(i))
```

so please help

Comment: How can you use `i` in the third argument to `range()`? The arguments to a function are evaluated before the function is called, but `i` isn't set until `range()` returnes.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish with this? How can the range step be a function of `i` if `i` isn't known until after you calculate the range?

Comment: thats wht i am asking . how can i do this?

Comment: What you're trying to do makes no logical sense. The range depends on the step, so the step can't depend on the range values.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically change the step during the loop?

Comment: i wanna print 1 , 2 ,4,8,16... series in this way @Barmar

Comment: yep i wanna change the step value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `range()`. The arguments to `range()` are just evaluated once, when the loop starts, not each time through the loop, and it effectively calculates the entire list of values at the start (it actually uses an iterator object internally, but that doesn't change this). The sequence can't be changed during the loop.

Do it with a `while` loop that recalculates `i` itself.

```
i = 1
while i < 11:
    print(i)
    i = fun(i)
```

If you really want to use `for`, you could define a generator function that returns your sequence of values.

```
def multrange(init, end, step):
    i = init
    while i < end:
        yield i
        i = i * step

for i in multrange(1, 11, 2):
    print(i)
```

You can even define a generator that takes the function to use to generate the next step as an argument.

```
def generic_range(init, end, stepper):
    i = init
    while i < end:
        yield i
        i = stepper(i)

for i in generic_range(1, 11, fun):
    print(i)
```

Comment: that is the thing man i wanna do this ussing for loop not with while

Comment: You could define your own generator function that returns the values you want, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Like what [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) mentioned, the `range()` function is only evaluated once. The behavior you seek is best accomplished through a while loop.

If you'd like to insist on a for loop however, you may explore the following options:

1. Define a generator function and then use a `for` loop that iterates from it ([the answer by Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331384/how-can-we-send-for-loop-variable-as-the-function-argument-in-python/60331402#60331402))
2. Use a `for` loop with `enumerate`:

```py
step = 0 # Initialize variable `step`
for index, x in enumerate(range(1, 30)):
    if index == step:
        print(x)
        # set the next index for which to
        # output a value
        step = fun(x) + index
```